# Fibre product in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I would be thankful if anyone can guide me in writing commands for a fibre product in LaTeX. I would also like to know how to change the angle of the diagram as I want it to be.

Comment: You can use `tikz`s `\matrix` command inside the `tikzpicture` environment. See the manual for more details: http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf

Comment: `tikz-cd`, definitely.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One option would be to use [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd); the package documentation contains numerous examples; in the example code below two variants for a pullback (fibre product) diagram:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
Q
\arrow[bend left]{drr}{q_2}
\arrow[bend right,swap]{ddr}{q_1}
\arrow[dashed]{dr}[description]{u} & & \\
& P \arrow{r}{p_2} \arrow{d}[swap]{p_1}
& Y \arrow{d}{g} \\
& X \arrow[swap]{r}{f}
& Z
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}
{} & Q
\arrow[bend right,swap]{ddl}{q_1}
\arrow[bend left]{ddr}{q_2}
\arrow[dashed]{d}[description]{u} & & \\
& P \arrow{dr}{p_1} \arrow{dl}[swap]{p_2} \\
X \arrow[swap]{dr}{f} & & 
Y \arrow{dl}{g} \\
& Z
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How might one insert the equivalent of a lrcorner symbol in the latter diagram to notate that the diagram is in fact a pushout?